# How do I access Cofoundry settings and other dependency injected classes in theme views

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, cofoundry

I have defined a settings class with theme specific settings - in this case the site's main title:

```
public class ThemeSettings : IConfigurationSettings
{
    [Required]
    public string SiteTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to include the site title in my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
_Layout.cshtml:

<h2 class="header-title">  ... INSERT TITLE HERE ... </h2>
```

But how can I get the `ThemeSettings` class injected in a view file without a controller behind it, such that I can access the property `SiteTitle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor files support dependency injection in ASP.NET Core:

```html
@inject ThemeSettings themeSettings 

<h2 class="header-title">@themeSettings.SiteTitle</h2>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. Working on my .Net Core Fu.